# How to set the height of the split action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'am using the `ActionBarSherlock` and meet a strange problem, I can set the height of the `ActionBar` at the top, but the split `ActionBar` at the bottom is to big.

I want to know how to set the height of the split action bar?

thanks!

Comment: Add essential code fragments to your question, please. :)

Comment: Thansks~  I have solved the problem, it's because the actionbar icon is too big, when i fixed the icon size, the height of the actionbar is changed.  And this site   http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/   gives the icon size for actionbar for different device dpi.

Comment: With these information answer your own question and mark it as solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself, it's because the actionbar icon is too big, when i fix the icon size, the height of the actionbar become normal. I've learnt that the size of the icon must adapt the device dpi. 
And this site: 
http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/
gives the icon size for different device dpi.