# Split Action Bar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.4-kitkat

With a split action bar, is it possible to set different heights for the top and the bottom? Or is there just one `<item name="android:height">` for the entire thing?

There has to be a way... If you had a huge split bar on the top with tabs and stuff, you wouldn't want to have a giant bottom split bar. hmm

Comment: So you're asking that you want your action bar to be of different heights at different positions ?

Comment: Yes, right now my action bar is 70dp, but i'd like the "split" action bar to be smaller.

Comment: Have you tried Jake Wharton's Action Bar implementation ? Its known as Sherlock.

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock might be of help !!

Comment: Couldn't find any answers with ActionBarSherlock  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954637/how-to-set-the-height-of-the-split-action-bar